# Use ECMA6 Array methods in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

Can I use the new ECMA6 Array methods, such as `find()` and `includes()` in Typescript? They seem to work, despite the fact that the compiler says:

```
error TS2339: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'User[]'.
```

[The documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html#classes) implies that it should work when it says

> TypeScript supports new features in JavaScript, like support for
>   class-based object-oriented programming.

So why does it give me an error?

Comment: What version of TypeScript?

Comment: Also can you add some of your code so we can see what `User[]` is defined as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the `target` in `tsconfig.json` is set to `"ES6"`:

```
"target": "ES6" // under "compilerOptions"
```

That will make it include the [definition file](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b0584b58fa07ee8c06e6d6f0f1bce2d4c37c7640/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L4139) with `find(..)` found in `Array<T>`.

**Example**

```
// test.ts
var a: number[];

a.find(n => n === 3);
```

Then compiling:

```
tsc test.ts --target ES6 // ok
tsc test.ts --target ES5 // error: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'number[]'
```

**Polyfill**

If you don't want to target ES6 and instead are using a polyfill, then you can add this to a definition file to be used by your code:

```
interface Array<T> {
    find(predicate: (value: T, index: number, obj: Array<T>) => boolean, thisArg?: any): T;
}
```

Comment: Your answer *almost* answers my question -- there's just something I'm not getting. I thought Typescript was a superset (or near superset) of ECMA6 that could be compiled into ECMA5. Shouldn't it *intrinsically know* that Arrays have a `find()` method. Why do I need a polyfill?

Comment: @IanPhillips it will throw an error because those ES6+ methods don't always exist in an ES5 environment—when targeting ES5. The compiler doesn't generate the code for those polyfills so you have to provide your own and then specify a definition for them. On the other hand, if you target ES6 then the compiler will make the assumption that you are going to run the code in an ES6 environment where those methods exist and so it doesn't error.

Comment: I thought the Typescript compiler precisely *did* generate the code for those polyfills; much of what made me excited about Typescript was my belief that I could write Typescript code and compile it into Javascript that would run on crappy old browsers. And yet a quick test proves you right -- Typescript issues an error when targeting ES5 and leaves the `find()` method as-is.